# Select random element of array in Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a spider with scrapy

```
import scrapy

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "website"
    start_urls = [
    'https://website.com',
    ]
    def parse(self, response):
        for main in response.css('div#main'):
            yield {
            'link': random.choice(main.css('li.afinidades div.content ul li h5 a::text')[0].extract()),
            }
```

There are four elements «link», and I want to take them in random: now the 0, then the 3, then the 2, etc.

I tried this:

import scrapy

```
class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "website"
    start_urls = [
    'https://website.com',
    ]
from random import randrange
key = randrange(0, 3)
    def parse(self, response):
        for main in response.css('div#main'):
            yield {
            'link': random.choice(main.css('li.afinidades div.content ul li h5 a::text')[key].extract()),
            }
```

No results. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The `css()` function returns another `Selector` instance and not an array of the actual results. You have to select the index you want after the `extract()` function.

```
'link': main.css('li.afinidades div.content ul li h5 a::text').extract()[key]
```

Take a look at the Scrapy documentation about selectors if you need to know more. https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html